# PHP: Error using include_once function. Failed opening 'mysiteURL' for inclusion

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin, include-once

I have never used PHP and need it just to build my WordPress site with an installed theme.

Every time when I open any pages under my wp-admin, I'm getting a warning:

> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   ‘/myURL/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress/admin.php’
>   for inclusion (include_path=’.:/usr/local/php56/pear’) in
>   /myURL/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress123/dsidxpress.php
>   on line 90

When opening .php, I see the following code on line 90:

```
include_once(str_replace("\\", "/", WP_PLUGIN_DIR) . "/dsidxpress/admin.php");
```

After changing it per the instrucions:

```
include_once(include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear' . “/dsidxpress/admin.php”);
```

I'm getting new error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘=’ in /myURL/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress123/dsidxpress.php on line 90
```

How exactly do I need to change it?

Comment: `include_path=’.:/usr/local/php56/pear’` should definitely not go into a call to `include_once`, that's simply showing you the value of a system setting as a possible hint. I don't think that's going to help you much here.

Comment: What you should do instead is look at the file path it's trying to include and verify that the file still exists. Chances are, it does not. Look for: `wp-content/plugins/dsidxpress/admin.php`